# How to Pass Byte[] into webservice(.asmx) method dynamically using C#?

Tags: c#, web-services

I have a webservice which converts pdf into bytes

```
public T InvokeMethod<T>(string serviceName, string methodName, params object[] args)
    {

        object obj = this.m_webServiceAssembly.CreateInstance(serviceName);

        Type type = obj.GetType();

        return (T)type.InvokeMember(methodName, BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, obj, args);
    }
```

when i try to parse the byte[] as Object[] Array because it accepts object array when i parse values into this method it throws exception sometime it takes lots of time to convert pdf into byte[] .

My Requirement

```
I have dynamic web service i wana pass byte[] array into a method how to do this without adding static webreference
```

Comment: Convert to base64 encoding and give a try!

Comment: How it would work... Please Read my question once again i am calling Inbuilt .Net Method which passes only Object[] Array...i was asking for alternate solution..

Comment: base64 is encoding for binary data. If you could convert the file into base64, then you can pass it as a string to webService. I don't know whether it suits your requirment. Converting to base64 might be resource intensive task.

Comment: Thanks it didnt take too much time to append... :)